# monero-stratum Error When Compiling

Tags: monerod, daemon, compile, monero-stratum

Hi I seem to be getting an error during compiling of monero-stratum.

```
[ 60%] Linking CXX shared library libcnutil.so
[ 60%] Built target cnutil
Scanning dependencies of target hashing
[ 60%] Building C object hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/src/hashing.c.o
/home/miner/monero-stratum/hashing/src/hashing.c: In function 
‘cryptonight_hash’:
/home/miner/monero-stratum/hashing/src/hashing.c:5:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘cn_slow_hash’
 cn_slow_hash(input, len, output, variant, 0);
 ^
In file included from /home/miner/monero-stratum/hashing/src/hashing.c:1:0:
/home/miner/monero/src/crypto/hash-ops.h:82:6: note: declared here
void cn_slow_hash(const void *data, size_t length, char *hash);
  ^
hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 
'hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/src/hashing.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/src/hashing.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:123: recipe for target 'hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [hashing/CMakeFiles/hashing.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I followed the Ubuntu 16.04 directions.

Perhaps the recent update to the Monero Daemon caused this.

Please Help.

Comment: I'm going to download a docker version .. Boy I feel Lazy for not solving this.

Comment: Even the docker version of this did not compile. I think this is because of the fork .

Comment: It looks like part of the code was updated for variant 1, and part was not. Maybe one of these parts is an external dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) in the repo and it worked for me.

Boils down to running this:

```
apt-get -qq update
apt-get install -y -qq libboost-all-dev golang curl cmake build-essential libssl-dev git-core libunbound-dev libzmq3-dev 
curl -L -o ~/v0.12.0.0.tar.gz https://github.com/monero-project/monero/archive/v0.12.0.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf ~/v0.12.0.0.tar.gz -C ~/
pushd ~/monero-0.12.0.0 && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 . && make && popd
```

then running:

```
cmake .
make
```

from monero-stratum if you weren't in there already.

You may need to specify MONERO_DIR when runing `cmake .` in the monero-stratum repo per the directions on the repo homepage.

Answer (score 2):

install latest go from https://golang.org/dl/

create home/go/scr Add /usr/local/go/bin to the PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding this line to your /etc/profile (for a system-wide installation) or $HOME/.profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

create home/go/scr

follow https://github.com/sammy007/monero-stratum until error then

edit monero-stratum/hashing/src/hashing.c to looklike this

```
#include "crypto/hash-ops.h"

void cryptonight_hash(const char* input, char* output, uint32_t len) {
    const int variant = input[0] >= 7 ? input[0] - 6 : 0;
    cn_slow_hash(input, len, output);
}

void cryptonight_fast_hash(const char* input, char* output, uint32_t len) {
    cn_fast_hash(input, len, output);
}
```

then

```
cmake .
```

then

```
make
```